# Tamaño de fuente irregular en navegadores de determinados dispositivos Android

Tags: html, android, css

En el siguiente documento HTML :

> http://fiddle.jshell.net/v0yqL8xp/show/

Cuando se ejecuta en un dispositivo  **Android >= 8** y navegador **Chrome (79.03945.116)**, encuentro el siguiente problema relacionado con el tamaño de la fuente (`font-size: 16px;`):
Los dos div de la clase `.medium` reducen el texto en comparación a la clase `.large`
Si aumento el tamaño de la clase `.medium` al 100% el texto vuelve al tamaño correcto.

Alguien ha tenido algún problema similar?

> HTML y CSS: http://jsfiddle.net/v0yqL8xp/

**Snippet:**

```css
*
{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}


.medium
{
 float: left;
 width: 50%;
}

.large
{
 width: 100%;
}

p
{
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 16px;
 padding: 14px;
}
```

```html
<div class="medium">
 <p>Fugiat sit et tempor magna adipisicing excepteur veniam. Velit reprehenderit amet do et sint officia Lorem esse irure eiusmod consectetur. Laboris esse duis enim dolore et ex aliqua proident ullamco id ullamco nostrud amet. Qui culpa ad sint adipisicing do cillum velit proident exercitation ipsum. Pariatur reprehenderit reprehenderit elit irure ea cupidatat labore minim. Labore qui est minim occaecat commodo minim consectetur id aliquip. Sit veniam excepteur cupidatat eiusmod.</p>
</div>

<div class="medium">
 <p>Fugiat sit et tempor magna adipisicing excepteur veniam. Velit reprehenderit amet do et sint officia Lorem esse irure eiusmod consectetur. Laboris esse duis enim dolore et ex aliqua proident ullamco id ullamco nostrud amet. Qui culpa ad sint adipisicing do cillum velit proident exercitation ipsum. Pariatur reprehenderit reprehenderit elit irure ea cupidatat labore minim. Labore qui est minim occaecat commodo minim consectetur id aliquip. Sit veniam excepteur cupidatat eiusmod.</p>
</div>

<div class="large">
 <p>Fugiat sit et tempor magna adipisicing excepteur veniam. Velit reprehenderit amet do et sint officia Lorem esse irure eiusmod consectetur. Laboris esse duis enim dolore et ex aliqua proident ullamco id ullamco nostrud amet. Qui culpa ad sint adipisicing do cillum velit proident exercitation ipsum. Pariatur reprehenderit reprehenderit elit irure ea cupidatat labore minim. Labore qui est minim occaecat commodo minim consectetur id aliquip. Sit veniam excepteur cupidatat eiusmod.</p>
</div>
```

**Aqui podéis observar como el tamaño de la letra del div 1 y 2 es menor que la del  tercero**

[image: Aqui podéis observar como el tamaño de la letra del div 1 y 2 es menor que la del tercero]

Comment: Pienso que tu problema tiene que ver con las librerías que ocupas con tu CSS.